# return a value from a JS, through a getHyperlink method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, hyperlink

I've made a table in a website (ASP.net/C#) and in that table, there is a Delete button in each row. If the user clicks on the delete button, I'd like there to be a little pop-up, which asks whether he's sure he wants to delete it. Of course, depending on the answer, the system deletes the object, or not.

I currently use this piece of code, which works, but I can't get the return value of the code.

```
getHyperLink(item, "ibDelete").Attributes.Add("onClick", "return confirm('You sure you wanna delete all this shizzle?')");
```

Does anybody know how I can get a return value from that statement? Thank you in advance :)

EDIT: 
below there is a method declared which is probably relevant. I'm not to sure of things myself as I haven't written this part.

```
  public HyperLink getHyperLink(RepeaterItem item, string name)
    {
        return (HyperLink)item.FindControl(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom function like below to obtain the user input.

```
    function deleteRow(rowindex){
        var message = "You sure you wanna delete all this shizzle?";
        var input = confirm(message);
        if(input){
        // user has pressed OK
        return true;
        } 
        else{
        // user has cancelled
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Your code could look like:

```
    getHyperLink(item, "ibDelete").Attributes.Add("onClick", "return deleteRow(itemIndex)");
```

Comment: mmhm that certainly looks good, but the items that have to be deleted are stored in a DB, so they have to be deleted there as well. Is there some way to do all of it in the server-side (C#)? As I think that'd be more efficiënt, than to switch back and forth a few times.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the input of the user? You have to post a form with an action of telling the server 'delete row X'. When the server has completed the task, you should redirect to the same page and reload the data into the table from the database.